# Python Dictionary: Output dictionary within a list within a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary with a lot of keys. One of those keys has a list of dictionaries; i want to extract data from the ladder dictionary.

It looks like this:

```
Data = {
(...)
Users:[{'username':'X','email':'Y'},{'username':'W','email':'Z'}]
(...)
}
```

And I want to create a list with all the emails, so that

```
print(listEmails)
>['Y','Z']
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print([user.get('email') for user in Data['Users']])
```

That is assuming `Users` from your sample is actually str - `'Users'`

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot